# [ExoPlayer]Delete one media cache use SimpleCache and DefaultDatabaseProvider

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

The `com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache` class provides a static method (`com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache#delete`) to delete all cached data. Now I want to delete the cache of only one media. Is there any way to do it?

like this:

```java
public static void deleteOneMediaCache(MediaItem mediaItem){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you should use non-static `cache.removeResource(mediaItemKey)`. You can obtain `cache` instance from `CacheDataSource.Factory`.
Please, see [docs](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/cache/Cache.html#removeResource(java.lang.String)) for more info.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33638395)